# Configure Eclipse to avoid comments wrapping

Tags: eclipse

When I'm writing code, I keep format it using CTRL + SHIFT + F. Everything works fine except comments, Eclipse wrapes comments and its very annoying. I just want single line comment, no matter how long it is.

For example

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    int someValue = 155; // This value is for blah blah blah blah
}
```

after format

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    int someValue = 155; // This value is 
                         // for blah blah 
                         // blah blah
}
```

Now its taking 3 lines for nothing.

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2, anyway to fix it ?

Comment: Think about using a JavaDoc comment instead of a normal comment for the above situation. That has additional benefits like Eclipse showing your comment as tooltip when hovering over the variable name at any place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
2. Choose the current active formatter profile , press edit and you will the following screen.
3. The `Comments` tab contains all the stuff about comments formatting. Set the `Maximum line width for comments` to a very large number.

[image]